# Conditional Formatting Rows With Date Formula

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I am trying to conditional format a date range within a sheet. I can conditionally format the cell easily, but can't figure out how to do the entire row. Here is the formula I am using.

```
=$C:$C=Today()-30
```

The formula is not incorrect based on what google says, but the cell will go from red back to white.

Answer (score 2):

To apply conditional formatting with a custom formula to a range, write the formula for the cell in the upper left corner of the range. It will be correctly adjusted for other cells, using relative/absolute references in your formula.

In the specific case, the formula should be `=C1 = Today()- 30` (if the range you are formatting has C1 as upper left corner).

Answer (score 1):

Please select the columns that comprise "one row" and then  Format, Conditional formatting..., Custom formula is:

```
=$C1=today()-30
```

select your formatting and <kbd>Done</kbd>. (The `$` is required if to apply formatting to more than one cell in this way.)

Since "30 days ago or more" is a much more common requirement than just "30 days ago" you might want to consider `=$C1<=today()-30`.